# Custom Callout view does not want to appear

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

**FINAL EDIT** I pretty much rebuilt all of my classes (custom MKAnnotationView, custom callout view, and another custom class that supports the MKAnnotation protocol (this is my annotation class)), and it just kind of started working and showing the callout. I brought everything down to the bare essentials (i.e. used just a custom annotation view without using a custom callout, and then re-implemented the custom callout) in a test project to see things more clearly, it then worked, and I ported my results back to my actual project. The callout view is displayed but not properly (my custom detailCalloutAccessoryView is cut off, still trying to fix that).

---

My MapKit custom callout view just does not want to freaking appear when I tap my custom annotation view. What is wrong with my code ?

Here is my "viewForAnnotation" function... the custom annotation views work just fine, it's just the callout views that are not appearing (at all).

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if let annotation = annotation as? RentalAnnotation {
            let identifier = "pin"
            var customAnnotationView: CustomAnnotationView

    var customCalloutView = CustomCalloutView()
    customCalloutView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customCalloutView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)
    customCalloutView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customCalloutView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
    customCalloutView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

    let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bed"))
    image.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    if let dequeuedView = rentalsMapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier) as? CustomAnnotationView {
        dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
        dequeuedView.label!.text = "$ \(annotation.price)"
        dequeuedView.canShowCallout = true
        dequeuedView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = customCalloutView
        customAnnotationView = dequeuedView
    } else {
        customAnnotationView = CustomAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        customAnnotationView.label?.text = "$ \(annotation.price)"
        customAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true
        customAnnotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = customCalloutView
        customAnnotationView.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: +5, y: 5)

    }
    return customAnnotationView
}
return nil
```

}

Here is my code for the CustomCalloutView subclass (of UIView):

```
class CustomCalloutView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var calloutPropertyAvailabilityDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var calloutPropertyBedroomNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var calloutPropertyBathroomNumber: UILabel!
    var customCalloutView = UIView()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        customCalloutView = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomCalloutView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView)!
        self.addSubview(customCalloutView)
    }

}
```

I have designed my custom callout view interface with an XIB file which as 6 labels and a button.

What am I doing wrong ? I have tried literally everything... still can't get it to work.

**EDIT** Code for RentalAnnotation

```
class RentalAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var rentalName: String
    var price: Int
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(rentalName: String, price: Int, latitude: Double, longitude: Double, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.rentalName = rentalName
        self.price = price
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }

    var title: String? {
        return rentalName
    }

    var subtitle: String? {
        return ("$\(price)")
    }

    func mapItem() -> MKMapItem {
        let addressDictionary = [String(CNPostalAddressStreetKey): rentalName]
        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDictionary)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = rentalName
        return mapItem
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2** Code for didSelectAnnotationView method

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
        if ((view.annotation?.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation)) == true) {
            return
        }

        var customView = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomCalloutView", owner: self, options: nil))[0] as? CustomCalloutView

//        var calloutFrame = customView?.frame
//        calloutFrame?.origin = CGPointMake(-((calloutFrame?.size.width)!/2) + 15, -((calloutFrame?.size.height)!))
//        customView?.frame = calloutFrame!

        let cpa = view.annotation as? CustomPointAnnotation
//
//        view.addSubview(customView!)

        let spanX = 0.0000000000000001
        let spanY = 0.0000000000000001

        let newRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: (cpa?.coordinate)!, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY))
        self.rentalsMapView.setRegion(newRegion, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Does your annotation have a title?

Comment: Not right now, why ?

Comment: How would I set one ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a `title` to your annotation. The callout is not showed if the `title` is `nil`.
From the documentation:

> SWIFT
>   var canShowCallout: Bool
>   OBJECTIVE-C
>   @property(nonatomic) BOOL canShowCallout
>
> If the value of this property is YES, a standard callout bubble is
>   shown when the user taps a selected annotation view. The callout uses
>   the title and subtitle text from the associated annotation object. If
>   there is no title text, though, the annotation view is treated as if
>   its enabled property is set to NO. The callout also displays any
>   custom callout views stored in the leftCalloutAccessoryView and
>   rightCalloutAccessoryView properties.

Comment: I keep getting an error telling me that the title property is get-only. How can I fix that ? I am accessing the "title" property from my custom class that implements MKAnnotation...

Comment: You can add this to your custom class that implements MKAnnotation to return the title: var title: String? { get { return "your title" } }

Comment: I already have this:    var title: String? {
        return rentalName
    }

Comment: Can you please post your code of the class that implements the MKAnnotation protocol?

Comment: Just did... I really, REALLY don't understand why I'm still getting the error message... (I posted the code without the change you suggested, because even with the change, it wasn't working)

Comment: This is very strange, I tried to add a RentalAnnotation using your class and I see the callout. Do you implement the didSelectAnnotationView: method? If you deselect the annotation in didSelectAnnotationView: the callout is not displayed.

Comment: Even with your didSelectAnnotationView in my test app the callout is showed. I suggest to clean completely the project (cmd+maiusc+K) and rebuild it. Check also the rentalName of your annotations because this is the title and as mentioned above, if it's nil or an empty string the callous is not showed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103881/discussion-between-leonard-bonfils-and-lorenzoliveto).